# UserControl COM-Object changes Environment.OSVersion

Tags: c#, com, user-controls

related to my other Question herer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349726/microsoft-access-not-unloading-c-sharp-usercontrol

We have a C# UserControl which is COM-Enabled and embedded on an Access Form. I had several issuel with the hosted Control but one of the main issues I have is the following:

Environment.OSVersion while debug from Visual Studio:

```
Environment.OSVersion
{Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.10240.0}
    Platform: Win32NT
    ServicePack: ""
    Version: {10.0.10240.0}
    VersionString: "Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.10240.0"
```

which is correct.

Environment.OSVersion while debug from Microsoft Access (Attached to Access Prozess):

```
Environment.OSVersion
{Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0}
    Platform: Win32NT
    ServicePack: ""
    Version: {6.2.9200.0}
    VersionString: "Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0"
```

which is completly wrong. Something seams to override the OSVersion.

Anyone ever seen such a behavior with COM Objects? Or is it maybe a Bug in Windows 10?

UPDATE:
I testet the same thing on a windows 7 machine, which in both cases returns the right value

```
{Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1}
    Platform: Win32NT
    ServicePack: "Service Pack 1"
    Version: {6.1.7601.65536}
    VersionString: "Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1"
```

Comment: This is entirely normal.  Windows will treat older apps that never heard of Win10 kindly to make sure they don't get confused.  You cannot convince Access that it should know about it.  Since you run inside Access, you inherit its behavior.  Maybe next version of Office, not actually that likely.  Whatever your real problem might be, it doesn't have anything with this.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for the explanation. So the problem seems to be in the Webbrowser Control we are using. Maybe they rely internaly on the OSVersion for some things.